# How do I implement multiple views that react to onTouch?

Tags: android

Let's say I have MyActivity and inside my onCreate method I initialize MyBackgroundView, then MyPlayer1View then MyPlayer2View.  I want to be able to touch the screen, figure out if I have touched Player1 or Player2 and then respond with changes to the players if I have touched them.

My problem is, where do I put the onTouchListener?  Can only MyBackgroundView listen for touches, or can the players listen for touches too?  If MyBackgroundView can only accept touches, do I need to call view.ontouchlistener that says, you have touched me, and I have a player at those coordinates, so I'll pass the motion event to the player and let it handle it?  Or do call view.ontouchlistener in each of the players that says, you've touched me, now I will react to the motion event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can only MyBackgroundView listen for touches, or can the players listen for touches too?

`setOnTouchListener()` is available on all subclasses of `View`.